# Creating a list out of single entities

Tags: 2sxc

2sxc question. I have a lot of single entities of a content type that I want to combine into a list. Essentially, I have four columns and each column has an individual 2sxc content module in it. The column layout is controlled by DNN content panes. What I want to do is create a list template for that content type and add those individual items to the list. The columns would be created in the list template dynamically.

Is this advisable, or am I better off just recreating the content and using a new list template. If it is feasible, what steps would I have to take to make the conversion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy. The only question is if you want to manually choose which items to show in the list, or if you want to query it like a DB.

1. Manual approach: create a new template, say it's a list, and you're ready to go. You'll have to add "demo-items" and then "replace" them with the real one, so the initial setup has a lot of clicking.
2. Query-approach: create a new template, but then loop over the `App.Data["Type"]` instead of the `Data["Default"]`

ok?

Comment: I will go with option 1, since we want to control which items go in which list. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I should have mentioned that I am not doing one big list but several with different entries.